# Is it possible to change Drupal's coding standards or get around tiny spacing?

Tags: drupal, standards

In order to [submit a drupal module](https://www.drupal.org/node/7765), you must adhere to Drupal's [coding standards](https://www.drupal.org/coding-standards). The problem with the coding standards, is that it has one specific and very annoying standard: [indenting](https://www.drupal.org/coding-standards#indenting). I absolutely hate that the indenting is:

> Use an indent of 2 spaces, with no tabs.

If it was 4, then I could live with it. Is there any way to go about convincing Drupal to change these standards, or at the very least, is there a way others deal with this?  Perhaps a Netbeans plugin that shows single spaces as double or something similar?

Comment: Many people are using spaces instead of tabs to indent code. That makes no sense to me. Point of tabs is to give each person individually possibility to set them as they like. I like then to be 2 chars...I set my editor that way. And when I give you my code it will be displayed as it suits you best.

Comment: I very much doubt you will get them to change the standard. Everyone else is using 2 spaces, you want us all to change just for you? Really I don't see what the problem is. Just set up your editor to use spaces instead of tabs. I don't use netbeans, but I am sure you can set this up without a plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No one is going to change Drupal's coding standards.

You can write your code in your style but before submitting it, you can just "autoformat" all the code (Alt + Shift + F) with the Drupal coding standards which can be configured at: Tools -> Options -> Editor.

[image: NetBeans Editor configuration]